# Mongoose : copy document to another with mongoose middleware pre("remove")

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two documents User and Temp, i want to copy User collection to Temp collection when User is deleted, for this i want to use mongoose pre remove middleware :

```
const Temp = mongoose.model("TempModel");
...
UserSchema.pre("remove", async function (next) {
    console.log(`User is beign removed ${this._id}`);
    await Temp.create({ user: this._id });
    next();
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

When executing this, a have the console but the Temp.create is not working.

Something like this, is it possible ? thank you

Comment: if you use `async/await` you should not pass and call `next`

Comment: Hi, thank you but i want to know why?

Comment: `next` was being used to support asynchronous flow before mongoose support for async/await was introduced. You can also use `next` (without async/await) but the functionality is the same async/await.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your explanation

Comment: But my issue remains unsolved even i remove next

Comment: have you tried wrapping try / catch around `await Temp.create()` ?